# Can anyone come up with an interesting consequence of the Twin Prime Conjecture being true?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic, prime-numbers, open-problem, twin-primes

The question is in the title.  Was wondering if there are statements equivalent to or a consequence of the statement that there are infinitely many twin primes.

If not, then why is this conjecture a "terminal point" in mathematics considered interesting?

---

If this is not an easy question to answer, I am willing to accept known equivalent statements (or consequences).  The most elegant one wins.

I have a preference for algebraic statements over analytical.  The analytical statements are the majority of published attempts.  I dream of their being an algebraic approach.

Comment: What kind of consequence / application of the twin prime conjecture could match the allure of a very simple-to-state problem about numbers that has resisted humanity's best efforts for hundreds of years?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, never say never. To me, this is a very good question, it makes some of us... THINK.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I don't know.  So I asked.  Beats coming up with 10 bad ideas in succession.  Also if there is no application, then why do prestigious mathematicians waste time on it?  Clearly, the proof of it will contain near-statements and definitely interesting mathematics.

Comment: On a side note, there has to be a proof of the TPC, since it is intuitively obvious to everyone that it is true.

Comment: @WlodAA I'm not saying that it's a bad question to ask if there are any interesting consequences... I actually think that's quite a good question. What I'm arguing against is the notion that the conjecture isn't interesting on its own.

Comment: @WlodAA to me "interesting" is loosely defined as the number of connected applications in the "graph of math" together with how many times those theorems will be referenced in the future.

Comment: Application is of little consequence to many pure mathematicians. The problems are studied for their own sake.

Comment: @MattSamuel there is applications to all math, we just haven't reached the "speed of light in math" nor a near star nor a black hole.  Clearly, all of interesting, abstract math will be referenced as time approaches infinity.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, I am sorry to interpret your elegant comment in a negative way, shame on me.

Comment: I didn't even mention recent ideas in physics connected with number theory.  Physics being an ultimate application area in our universe.

Comment: @MattSamuel, "Application is of little consequence to many pure mathematicians."

I hope that this is not a common view. (i) Applications to the real world are exceptionally attractive to me; (ii) we are talking here about **mathematical applications**; this time, this kind of applications are attractive to at least half of the mathematical population; (iii) both kinds of applications serve as a research trampoline.

Comment: "If there's no application, then why do prestigious mathematicians waste time on it?"  Well, they don't view it as a waste of time. You sort of answer the question yourself when you say "clearly the proof will contain... interesting mathematics" and you even give the standard justification to palliate people who hate the idea of no practical applications when you point to the fact that often pure math finds application years down the road, usually in physics.

Comment: See my edits to the post, I added in an option that should allow someone to answer.

Comment: Also, why do I vote up peoples comments and they rarely return the favor?  Popularity contests suck.

Comment: With interesting consequence do you mean an application of it, if proven, or a consequence of that $p,p+2$ are both primes ? For example if $\pi(x) -x = O(x^{1/2+\epsilon})$ then $\zeta(s)$ has no zeros on $\Re(s) > 1/2$, this is a consequence allowing to deduce a lot of things on $\pi(x)$. Also do you know the random model for the primes and all the k-upples generalizations of the twin primes ?

Comment: @reuns I don't know enough Complex Analysis nor enough about RZF.  I could not accept that answer as best.  So probabably the first consequence (p, p+2 prime).

Comment: Doesn't it vex anyone else that primality is usually studied in ring theory & algebra, yet there's nothing about the prime differences?  Differences being a ring operation.  The only thing that maybe isn't algebraic is counting and infinite sets.  But maybe there's a way...

Comment: I think maybe I've misinterpreted the intention of your "why is... considered interesting?". It would certainly be disappointing if twin prime was solved and the "journey" involved no interesting math, and in practice these simple but difficult problems do tend to be more animating benchmarks than ends in themselves.

Comment: I talked to people who believe it can be proven and they talk about Schinzel' Hypothesis and the gaussian moat problem and other ring ideas.  They believe no different applications would follow from the simplest proof of the twins conjecture. Ofcourse this is just a comment and not an answer and very " speculative ", but for what it is worth to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The twin prime problem is the tip of an iceberg. Settling it might help us decide whether, for all even $k$, there are infinitely many pairs of primes differing by $k$, even whether there are infinitely many pairs of consecutive primes differing by $k$, and that might shed light on the question of whether for every admissible $m$-tuple $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_m)$ there are infinitely many $n$ such that all of the numbers $n+a_1,n+a_2,\dots,n+a_m$ are prime, and that might give us some insight into Schinzel's Hypothesis H (q.v.).

Comment: Could you provide a short definition of admissible?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_k-tuple#Admissibility

Comment: Someone please add in a nice algebraic answer like this one, or I'm going to have to give the highest rep person answering, the points :)

Comment: What does (q.v.) mean? :)

Comment: It's an abbreviation for quod vide.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know what application it will serve in the real world but long back out of curiosity, I wanted to find the asymptotic expansion of the $n$-th twin prime $q_n$ assuming the twin prime conjecture. I got something like

$$
q_n \sim \frac{n\log^2 n}{C}\bigg(1 + \frac{2\log\log n - 1}{\log n - 2}\bigg)^2
$$
where $C$ is twice the twin prime constant.

Comment: I am a bit confused by your asymptotic. $n \ln^2(n)$ is also asymptotic. You seem to have an idea about an error term or something like that , or maybe some kind of limit. And how did you arrive at it anyway ?

Answer (score 1):

Zhang's remarkable paper on infinitely many pairs of primes differing by less than $7 \times 10^6$ was brought all the way down to $246$ in a ploymath project initiated by Terrence Tao and sharpened by the latest works of James Maynard. The twin prime conjecture will imply that the bound can be further brought down form $246$ to $2$ which in turn would imply that there is a wealth of mathematical tools waiting to be discovered to be able to reduce the bound form $246$ to $2$.

Comment: why not edit your previous answer ?

Comment: Because its a completely different answer not related to the first so I thought it is best as a separate answer.