# Is every prime is the largest prime factor in some prime gap?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, analytic-number-theory

**Definition**: In the gap between any two consecutive odd primes we have one or more composite numbers. We define the largest of among all the prime factor of these composite as the maximal prime factor of the gap.

> **Claim**: Every prime is a maximal prime factor for some prime gap.

I am looking for a proof or disproof.

**Update 21 Dec 2019**: Conjecture verified for $p \le 10^{10}.$

**Update 7 Dec 2019**: [Question has been posted in MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/347801/largest-prime-factor-in-the-gap-between-two-consecutive-primes)

**Update 14-Aug-2020:** Fixed source code

```
p_test = 2                                    # contains the prime being tested
high = 0                                      # current deepest search
target = step = 10^6                          # target and step for tracking progress

while True:
    m = 2                                     # current multiplier
    p = previous_prime(next_prime(m*p_test))  # start of prime gap

    while True:
        q = next_prime(p)                     # end of prime gap
        n = p + 1
        mf= 2                                 # starting maximal factor

        while n < q:
            mf_n = prime_divisors(n)[-1]      # contains current maximal factor
            if mf_n > mf:
                mf = mf_n                     # contains final maximal factor
            if mf < p_test:
                n = n + 1
            else:
                break                         # early exit if bigger maximal factor found

        if mf == p_test:
            break                             # exit loop when maximal factor is found
        m = m + 1
        p = previous_prime(next_prime(m*p_test))

    if m > high:                              # Display new deepest search
        print (p, m)
        high = m

    if p > target:                            # Display progress
        print ("Reached", target)
        target = target + step

    p_test = next_prime(p_test)
```

Comment: Grimms conjecture ?

Comment: @Roddy MacPhee Not sure if this is equivalent to Grimm's conjecture...

Comment: @Nilotpal I was just pointing to grimms because it has an equivalent of the gaps between primes can't exceed the number of primes up to that point ( at least infinitely often).

Comment: This is true for all twin primes , except for 2 and 3.

Comment: For the conjecture, it does not make a difference whether the gap (2,3) is included or not.

Comment: I currently check upto $\ p=10^5\ $ , upto $\ 40\ 000\ $ , all primes occured.

Comment: Conjecture true upto $\ p=10^5\ $

Comment: @sirous 2 is not a twin prime. learn your definitions.

Comment: No insight here yet, but is there any reason to suspect that each prime factor can't occur infinitely many times? Empirically it seems to lean that way at the start.

Comment: arbitrarily long gaps @Trevor in any gap of $n$ at least 1 multiple of all primes less than $n$ exists in the gap.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Rather than the definition of a twin prime , which is strictly speaking difference $2$ , I wonder how it can be shown that the conjecture is true for every prime that is part of a twin prime.

Comment: @Peter, it's actually all primes under 50000 on my end for the $10^5$ test.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee I also checked the conjecture for the primes upto $\ 10^5\ $ (it turned out to be true until there) , but the comment seems to claim that the conjecture can be proven for every prime that is part of a twin prime. I would be interested in this partial result.

Comment: Me too. We know gaps at least as large as the nextprime after n, minus 1 exists prior to n# .

Comment: My program found this to be true for all primes less than $4\cdot10^8$.

Comment: Some observations: $59$ is the least prime $p$ for which $2p$ is not the location of the maximal prime factor in the gap containing $2p$, because $2\cdot59$ and $2\cdot61$ both occur between $113$ and $127$. Indeed, $59$ is not maximal until $18\cdot59=1062$ when it occurs between twin primes $1061$ and $1063$. The prime $1778321$ is not a maximal prime factor until the gap containing $550\cdot1778321$, and this is the latest I found in the range tested. (That is, all primes $p<4\cdot10^8$ are the maximal prime factor in a gap containing some multiple of $p$ less than or equal to $550p$.)

Comment: @nickgard That's pretty big. I think I can strop mine as I am still less than $10^6$. Your code is seems much faster, can you please share your code?

Comment: @nickgard I am studying the distribution of the ratio of lower bound of gap to  its maximal prime factor $m/p$. As expected these ratio are close to positive integers. $m/p \approx 2$ is most frequent followed by $m/p \approx 3$ followed by $m/p \approx 4$ and so on. I think it should be possible to find an asymptotic for this distribution.

Comment: The sequence, Greatest prime divisor of all composite numbers between $p$ and next prime, is tabulated at http://oeis.org/A052248 (but I don't see anything there that would be useful here).

Comment: @Trevor: $2$ can't appear infinitely often, because the only way $2$ appears is if the surrounding primes are of the form $2^n-1$ and $2^n+1$, and those can't simultaneously be prime infinitely often (Mersenne primes, Fermat primes).

Comment: @Greg does $3$ appear infinitely often? Is there a heuristic that suggests that there are infinitely many $n=2^r3^s$ such that $n-1$ and $n+1$ are both prime?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I've been running this in Mathematica for a few minutes, and so far the indications are that 3 probably appears infinitely often, but increasingly rarely. Only 13 times in the first 5mil so far. I'd also add that I think a good rule of thumb for prime-related questions along these lines are that unless there's a damned good reason for them not to, things will tend to happen infinitely many times.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Such heuristics would imply we have heuristics to support the infinitude of twin primes. So I guess it not going to be straight forward.

Comment: We certainly do have heuristics to support the infinitude of twin primes, Nilotpal, we even have conjectured asymptotics for the number of twin primes up to $x$ – what we don't have is *proofs*.

Comment: @Trevor at http://oeis.org/A078884 it has been run up to $10^{1000}$, with $61$ appearances of $3$. Your rule of thumb is good, but it may not apply to sequences growing as fast as $2^r3^s$. E.g., some heuristics suggest there are only finitely many primes of the form $2^n+1$ (because they really have to be $2^{2^n}+1$, which grows way fast).

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes I am aware of the twin prime heuristics which conjectures $\pi_2(x) = O(x/\log^2 x)$. What I am referring to is heuristics for twin primes of the form $2^r 3^s \pm 1$ which I believe would not be straight forward.

Comment: It's not just big-oh of $x/\log^2x$, Nilotpal, it's asymptotic to $Cx/\log^2x$ for a specific constant $C$, a much stronger claim. But what you wrote in the previous comment says it won't be straightforward to get heuristics for the current problem *because that would yield heuristics for twin primes*. But that just means heuristics for the current problem would give us something we already have, so it doesn't suggest anything about heuristics for the current problem.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes I am aware of all that and have in fact used it to calculate the asymptotic expansion of the $n$-th twin primes as in this answer. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3315826/can-anyone-come-up-with-an-interesting-consequence-of-the-twin-prime-conjecture/3315869#3315869 . I guess the difference in understanding is perhaps due to the fact that I usually do not feel the need to write everything in exhaustive details which in the hind sight is my bad.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I guess the straightforward heuristic would give that $n=2^r3^s$ has $n\pm1$ both prime with probability $\asymp 1/(r+s)^2$; the sum of this over all $r,s$ diverges. It's worth noting that, if we disregard twin primes, then the maximal prime factor in the gap goes to infinity (if I'm not mistaken, this follows from the finiteness of solutions to $S$-unit equations).

Comment: Thanks, @Greg I had a feeling $S$-unit equations were the way to go.

Comment: We could strengthen the conjecture to only consider the composites between twin primes and ask the question: is every prime a maximal prime factor between some pair of twin primes? A proof of that would be equivalent to proving the twin-prime conjecture, so must be just as difficult to solve, and yet it's a very similar question to the original. FWIW, I've checked this version is true for primes up to $5\cdot10^8$.

Comment: @nickgard My opinion is that if we involve twin primes, it will be a case of strengthening it a bit too far as we will have a conjecture which depends on another conjecture. If the twin prime conjecture turn out to be false, your version of the maximal prime factor conjecture will automatically be false. But the current version of the maximal prime factor conjecture may still be true i.e. it is does not depend on the twin prime being true.

Comment: You really don't need to update how far the verification got every few hours. Updating it every other day is enough.

Comment: @DanielFischer Fair enough. My code current code just check in intervals of $5 \times 10^8$ so I usually update at the end of step which is actually now getting slower as primes increase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As requested by Nilotpal Kanti Sinha in the comments, here's the code I used to check maximal prime factor occurrences for all primes up to $4\cdot10^8$.

This is written in Sage, which is basically Python 2 with built-in maths. Hopefully the functions *next_prime()*, *previous_prime()*, *prime_divisors()* and *max()* are all self-explanatory.

The approach is to test successive multiples of each prime to see if they are the maximal prime factor in the relevant prime gap.

```
def get_max_prime(n):
# Find the maximal prime factor in the prime gap containing n
    pp = previous_prime(n)
    np = next_prime(n)
    fs = set([])   # Set of all prime factors in the gap

    for c in range(pp+1, np):
        for p in prime_divisors(c):
            fs.add(p)
    return max(fs)

# target and step for tracking progress
target = 10**6
step = 10**6

p = 3       # The prime to be tested
high = 0    # Tracks the deepest search

while True:
    q = p   # q will be a multiple of p
    m = 0   # Will contain the maximal prime factor in a gap
    c = 1   # Multiplier

    while(m != p):
        c = c + 1
        q = p * c
        m = get_max_prime(q)

    if c > high:     # Display new deepest search
        print p,c
        high = c

    if p > target:   # Display progress
        print "Reached", target
        target = target + step

    p = next_prime(p)
```

Comment: I'm neither a professional mathematician or a professional programmer. This seemed a straightforward approach and I hope it's bug-free.

Comment: I am running your code for $p > 4\cdot 10^8$. What you are saying is that after reaching a high of $550$ for the prime $p = 1778321$ which is relatively small compared to $p > 4\cdot 10^8$, high has not crossed $550$ for any other prime after $p = 1778321$? is this understanding correct? This would be interesting is if there is an experimentally upper bound on the multiplier.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I decided to track the record high multipliers because I felt that the multiple always staying low would be evidence to support the conjecture. It seems likely that relatively quickly, for any prime, a suitable multiple occurs in a small prime gap and the prime is then a maximal prime factor. For example, $550\cdot1778321-1$ and $550\cdot1778321+3$ are cousin primes, so the gap has just three composite integers. None of this is proof, of course; it's just evidence.

Comment: I found the next high new high of $783$ for the prime $725175083$.

Comment: so forcomposite for the outer for, and fordivfactored equates to both in PARI GP.  your version might be parallelizable in PARI GP via parfor.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee I agree it could be parallelizable, but I don't see we can gain much from more calculations. We can never find a counterexample because for any prime $p$ there are infinitely many $p$-smooth numbers that might yield a maximal prime factor, and, obviously, we can't test every prime.

Comment: @nickgard Found a new high of $819$ for the prime $2739366569$.